# PHP - Función define() con funciones?

Tags: php

He leído que define() puede trabajar con Array() pero, quisiera saber si se puede "definir" una función.

Algo así como:

```
function hw(echo 'Hello World');
define('funcionPrueba', hw());
```

Es eso posible? Y si es posible, qué tan optimizado es o qué problemas pueden surgir?

Comment: vienes de nodejs?

Comment: No, sólo es curiosidad al manejo de variables en PHP. Soy Aprendiz.

Comment: En tu ejemplo no estas pasando una función, estas pasando el resultado de evaluar la función ya que estas invocando a hw con los paréntesis, y almacenas en 'funcionPrueba' un [void](http://php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Si** es posible, más que nada porque no arroja ningún error si lo usamos, pero igual creo que **no** está pensado para pasar funciones y al mi parecer no tiene *mucho sentido/uso*.

Quiero demostrar algunos ejemplos de comportamientos si pasamos una función al `define()`.

---

> Ejemplo #1:

```
define( 'FOO', foo() );

function foo() {

    echo "Hola, caracola!\n";
}

echo "Primera linea\n";

FOO;

echo "Última linea";

// Resultado:
// => Hola, caracola! // Antes de la primera linea?
// => Primera linea
// => Última linea
```

Este comportamiento parece muy extraño, pero claro esta que el resultado proviene de la linea `define( 'FOO', foo() );` directamente.

---

> Ejemplo #2:

```
define( 'FOO', foo() );

function foo() {

    return "Hola, caracola!\n";
}

echo "Primera linea\n";

echo FOO;

echo "Última linea";

// Resultado:
// => Primera linea
// => Hola, caracola! // Ahora si esta en órden
// => Última linea
```

En este ejemplo hemos cambiado en la función el `echo` con el constructor `return` y si nos ha dado el resultado deseado, **pero que conste que la función `foo()` si se ha llamado**, como lo hemos comprobado en el ejemplo #1, solo que el resultado del `return` nos la hemos llevado al sitio deseado.

Podríamos pasar también un array en:

- [PHP 7 - Ver demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/92a33d4cc46aebf4b480b212db184bcb48423dc3)

y con la función [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.serialize.php) también es posible a partir de la versión:

- [PHP 5.4 - Ver demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ff4e092b099c571deff9c697e47a3dadfc607ce7)

Un dato más, es posible definir (a partir de PHP 5.6) con la constante clase `const` y pasar un array directamente, pero no funcionaria si pasamos una [función](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9350a02e10796aa799684732fff4ca25e78a18fc).

- [PHP 5.6 "const" - Ver demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10f7280104f0584b8b07c6d4ffceacb833f82aa7)

Para ser más claro aún del comportamiento del ejemplo #2:

```
define( 'FOO', foo() );

function foo() {

    return microtime(true);
}

echo FOO;   // => 1480605402.8959
echo foo(); // => 1480605402.8959

sleep(1);

echo FOO;   // => 1480605402.8959
echo foo(); // => 1480605403.896

sleep(1);

echo FOO;   // => 1480605402.8959
echo foo(); // => 1480605404.8962
```

Como vemos no cambia la constante `FOO` porque ya fue definida.

---

**Conclusión:**

Yo personalmente nunca he usado `define()` para pasar funciones de esta manera como lo hemos demostrado, pero si he usado para pasar fechas con la función `date()`:

```
define('COPYRIGHT', ' &copy; '.date('Y'));

// => © 2016
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

Según el [manual de PHP para la función define()](http://php.net/define), solo se admiten valores escalares (integer, float, string, boolean o NULL). Adicionalmente, PHP 7 acepta un array.

Es posible también pasarle [recursos](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), pero su uso no está recomendado ya que puede provocar comportamientos no deseados.